# Why doesn't Python throw an Index Error for the following case?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, if-statement, boolean

I came across this Python scenario in an **"if"** conditional statement involving Boolean operations. Whenever there is an index error in the condition, Python treats it as False rather than throwing an **Index Error**. What is the reason for this behavior.

**Sample Scenario:**

```
lst = [3, 4, 23, 5, 25, 76]
n = len(lst)
if n < 5 and lst[6] > lst[2]:
    print True
print False
```

**Output:**

```
False
```

As you can see, why does Python return **False**?, I was expecting it to throw an **Index Error**. Can someone explain what is happening behind the scene.

Comment: Because the second half of the `if` doesn't need to be evaluated if it's false... (it can short circuit) change it to `n < 20` for example... or change the `and` to `or`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `and` in an `if` statement is like writing two `if` statements, one inside the other:

```
if n < 5:
    if lst[6] > lst[2]:
        print True
```

In this case it is obvious why the second `if` doesn't raise an error if `n` is not less than 5: it is never executed. Combining them in a single `if` has exactly the same behavior due to the short-circuiting feature already described by others.

The "long" way of writing `or`, by the way, is like this:

```
# if x == 0 or 1/x > 0.01: print True
if x == 0:
    print True
elif 1/x > 0.01:
    print True
```

Here we avoid division by zero (an error) by only calculating `1/x` if x is not zero. The same applies in the single-`if` version with `or`. Since `x == 0` is true in that case, the truth value of the expression is known from evaluating that term, so the second term need not be evaluated.

Comment: Although this answer is of use to the original questions author, one should note that this method of decomposition into nested if statements does not scale well for nested and/or concatenated expressions involving 'and' and 'or'. At some stage it is best to learn to use the explanation of short-circuit operators that only evaluate the stuff on their RHS if it could possibly make a difference to the overall expression result (and so possibly ignoring side effects such as the index error of the original).

Comment: Yes, I wasn't really suggesting that they should be written this way (although sometimes, when an individual `if`'s condition gets too gnarly, it can make sense); it was just an aid to understanding.

Comment: Hi @kindall, sorry for the confusion. My comment was not aimed at you but at Arunprasath Shankar and future readers with the aim of trying to remind them to persevere with understanding the short-circuit explanation at some stage of their development. :-)

Answer (score 10):

In your example n = 6, so n is not < 5.  Python short-circuits boolean logic, so the second half of the and expression is skipped.

Answer (score 4):

`and` in Python makes use of [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), meaning that if its first argument evaluates to false (as `n < 5` does), then the second argument is left unevaluated since the result of the entire expression *must* be false at that point. Therefore, `lst[6] > lst[2]` is never evaluated.

Now let's try with `&`, which does *not* short-circuit:

```
>>> lst = [3, 4, 23, 5, 25, 76]
>>> n = len(lst)
>>> if (n < 5) & (lst[6] > lst[2]):
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This gives the result you expected.

Comment: @JonClements Well `&` behaves similarly to `and` in a boolean context except that it doesn't short-circuit, which is the important distinction here. Of course `or` would work too.

Answer (score 2):

Python stops evaluating conditions as soon as possible when the result is already known. In your example `n < 5` is `False` so in case of a conjunction (`and`) there is no need to evaluate the second part - it's irrelevant as whatever it would evaluate to, the whole expression is known at the moment to be `False`.

The same goes with `or` expressions if the first condition is `True`, thus:

```
if not (n >= 5 or lst[6] <= lst[2]):
```

also won't throw.

This mechanism is called [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).